# C# Vector of Object

Tags: c#

I can't figure this out i want to:

Write a program that saves a Vector of the Parkeringsbot type by printing each instance in a way that can be read in again. The program must be divided into several methods: Save(), Print(Parkeringsbot p) and the main method that calls Save().

The printout should look like this, as accurately as possible, so that it can be loaded using a corresponding Load() method:

FEN292 2021-03-17 13:47 500
FEN292 2021-04-17 12:14 600
FEN292 2021-04-18 13:47 500
BLB296 2021-04-10 13:30 500
BLB296 2021-04-15 16:17 800

Here is the code i have now:

```
using System;

namespace Code
{
  
    class Program
    {
        static Parkeringsbot[] parkeringsböter = new Parkeringsbot[5];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fill();

            
            Ladda();
        }

        static void Spara()
        {

        }

        static void SkrivUt(Parkeringsbot p)
        {
                
        }

        static void Ladda()
        {
            foreach (Parkeringsbot bot in parkeringsböter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{bot.bilnummer} {bot.tid} {bot.bot}");
            }
        }

        // slut svar.

        static public void Fill()
        {
            parkeringsböter[0] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 03, 17, 13, 47, 00), 500);
            parkeringsböter[1] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 04, 17, 12, 14, 00), 600);
            parkeringsböter[2] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 04, 18, 13, 47, 00), 500);
            parkeringsböter[3] = new Parkeringsbot("BLB296", new DateTime(2021, 04, 10, 13, 30, 00), 500);
            parkeringsböter[4] = new Parkeringsbot("BLB296", new DateTime(2021, 04, 15, 16, 17, 00), 800);
        }
    }

    class Parkeringsbot
    {
        public string bilnummer;
        public DateTime tid;
        public int bot;

        public Parkeringsbot(string bilnummer, DateTime tid, int bot)
        {
            this.bilnummer = bilnummer;
            this.tid = tid;
            this.bot = bot;
        }
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by saving a vector of a type?

Comment: Sorry i meant save as datatype Vector

Comment: And you want to save to... disk? A database? Cloud storage of some form?

Comment: isn't "vector" a C/C++ term for what in C# would be a List or Array?

Comment: Yes as an Array

Comment: @HansKeﬆing to be fair, the IL spec (ECMA 335) does define "vector" in the context of .NET, in II.14.1: "Vectors are single-dimension arrays with a zero lower bound." - so, in C#: a `Foo[]` for any `Foo`

Comment: I would suggest checking out the StreamWriter/StreamReader classes, as well as String.Split. And for more serious applications, see serialization libraries like Json .net

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is serialization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)

Using json.net makes it easier:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"parkeringsböter.json"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(parkeringsböter))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
}

// read
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parkeringsbot[]>(File.ReadAllText(@"parkeringsböter.json"));
```

See: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonSerializer

Answer (score 0):

I'll just modify and keep the ö in (nice test ! never had a variable with Swedish characters ! it works)

This is line oriented input with 4 space delimited terms. Two of these terms belong to the date. I will avoid static fields, you won't need them. When the date format will not change, below code works (I've tested)

```
public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + "parkeringsböter" + ".txt";
        Console.WriteLine("Fill test data");
        Parkeringsbot[] parkeringsböter = Fill();  // fill records and create the list
        Console.WriteLine("Save test data");
        Spara(fileName, parkeringsböter);
        Console.WriteLine("Load test data");
        parkeringsböter = Ladda(fileName);   // load the list from file
        Console.WriteLine("List result");
        RapporteraResultater(parkeringsböter); // dump the list
    }

    static void Spara(string fName, Parkeringsbot[] parkeringsböter)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var pb in parkeringsböter) SkrivUt(list,pb);
        File.WriteAllLines(fName, list.ToArray());
    }

    static void SkrivUt(List<string> lst, Parkeringsbot p)
    {
        lst.Add($"{p.bilnummer} {p.tid} {p.bot}");
    }

    static Parkeringsbot[] Ladda(string fName)
    {
        var list = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetTempPath()+"\\"+"parkeringsböter"+".txt" ).ToList();
        var parkeringsböter = new Parkeringsbot[list.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            var stok = s.Split(' ');
            parkeringsböter[i] = new Parkeringsbot(stok[0], DateTime.Parse(stok[1]+" "+stok[2]), int.Parse(stok[3]));
            i++;
        }
        return parkeringsböter;
    }

    static public void RapporteraResultater(Parkeringsbot[] parkeringsböter)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var pb in parkeringsböter) SkrivUt(list, pb);
        foreach (var s in list) Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
   

    static public Parkeringsbot[] Fill()
    {
        var parkeringsböter = new Parkeringsbot[5];
        parkeringsböter[0] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 03, 17, 13, 47, 00), 500);
        parkeringsböter[1] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 04, 17, 12, 14, 00), 600);
        parkeringsböter[2] = new Parkeringsbot("FEN292", new DateTime(2021, 04, 18, 13, 47, 00), 500);
        parkeringsböter[3] = new Parkeringsbot("BLB296", new DateTime(2021, 04, 10, 13, 30, 00), 500);
        parkeringsböter[4] = new Parkeringsbot("BLB296", new DateTime(2021, 04, 15, 16, 17, 00), 800);
        return parkeringsböter;
    }
}

public class Parkeringsbot
{
    public string bilnummer;
    public DateTime tid;
    public int bot;

    public Parkeringsbot(string bilnummer, DateTime tid, int bot)
    {
        this.bilnummer = bilnummer;
        this.tid = tid;
        this.bot = bot;
    }

}
```